# What aspect of Azure App Service determines the elapsed time limit?

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core

What in Azure App Service determines the elapsed time limit? The controller method...

```
[Route("service")]
[HttpPost]
public Outbound Post(Inbound inbound)
{
    Debug.Assert(inbound.Message.Equals("Hello server."));
    Outbound outbound = new Outbound();
    long Billion = 1000000000;
    for (long i = 0; i < 30 * Billion; i++) // 215 seconds
        ;
    outbound.Message = String.Format("The server processed inbound object.");
    return outbound;
}
```

The client side...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Post().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    static async Task<Outbound> Post() 
    {
        Outbound outbound = null;
        Inbound inbound = new Inbound();
        inbound.Message = "Hello server.";
        Task<Outbound> task = PostInbound(inbound);
        outbound = await task;
        // the assert sometimes fails because outbound is null
        Debug.Assert(outbound.Message.Equals("The server processed inbound object."));
        return outbound;
    }   
    static async Task<Outbound> PostInbound(Inbound inbound)
    {
        Outbound outbound = null;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000.0d);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://z.azurewebsites.net/", UriKind.Absolute);
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> task0 = 
            client.PostAsJsonAsync<Inbound>(
                 new Uri("controller/service", UriKind.Relative),
                 inbound);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await task0;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            Task<Outbound> task1 = content.ReadAsAsync<Outbound>();
            outbound = await task1;
        }
        return outbound;
    }
```

The failure is that the deserialized object reference is sometimes null. In other words the Outbound object reference is null. Failure is very likely beyond the number of iterations shown.